# Cannot open OSX agent

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, remote-access

I've just installed OSX agent (to remotely build, run, and debug iOS apps created using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova)
in iOS. When I want to open it (vs-mda-remote), it gives me an error:

```
vs-mda-remote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
0.2.7

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/lib/cli.js:46
    'lang': process.env.LANG.replace(/_.*/,""), // Convert "en_US.UTF8" to
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/lib/cli.js:46:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/bin/vs-mda-remote:10:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found a solution.

The problem was in the node, cordova and remote agent version.

First of all I have OS X Yosemite and not Mavericks but still it works.
Don't download the newest version of the Node from nodejs.org, look for the other releases folder on the website.

1) Install **node version 0.10.35**;
2) **cordova 4.0.0**;
3) **remote agent 0.2.6**.

And everything should work perfectly.